# Node.JS System Resources Monitoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to obtain values for system resources so that I can load those values into a sql database for tracking and debugging. I need to gather CPU usage per individual cores and RAM (min/max or %).

I have tried 'os' which gives a lot of data in a mostly useless format. I have seen very messy examples of people trying to phrase and use calculus the date into something meaningful, but that is a lot for something that seems so simple.

I have also played with 'os-utils' but it doesn't have a CPU break down.

Can anyone recommend me a solution?

Comment: Monitoring a process internally doesn't make much sense because this will take a considerable but unknown amount of resources. As for monitoring it externally, there's a lot of solutions that aren't specific to Node but PM2+Keymetrics may be a good start.

Comment: Does any of this help? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cpu%20utilization

Comment: @estus its not constant monitor. Just afew time a day. Its just to make sure we are over utilizing and handling demands..

Comment: @Jack yes, i have been there.

Comment: All the more external monitor serves this purpose better because you will need to have control over it to activate and deactivate it.